# python pivot table that group by a column (month) and sum all the value from other column grouped by the months

Tags: python

Im stuck tryin to index after a grouby and sum here is the code and the result

```
Count.groupby(Count.MesEntrada % 100)['Hipoges Value Total'].sum()

MesEntrada
1     1.012410e+07
2     2.585200e+07
3     8.185106e+07
4     9.896478e+06
5     3.551263e+07
6     3.187036e+07
7     1.233078e+07
8     1.115747e+07
9     7.350286e+06
```

10    1.203782e+07

Now im tryin to index so once i export it the data looks grouped by the months like the df(Count)

but im writing this code and doesnt works

```
Count1= Count.to_frame(name = 'Hipoges Value Total').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the correct way to do what i need it.

```
Count1 = Count.groupby(['MesEntrada'],as_index=False)['Hipoges Value Total'].sum()
Count1

MesEntrada  Hipoges Value Total
 0  1   1.012410e+07
 1  2   2.585200e+07
 2  3   8.185106e+07
 3  4   9.896478e+06
 4  5   3.551263e+07
 5  6   3.187036e+07
 6  7   1.233078e+07
 7  8   1.115747e+07
 8  9   7.350286e+06
 9  10  1.203782e+07
```